# Automaticaly open xls file on program start?

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

To provide our users to edit excel files without ms excel, we have made a simple app with visual studio 2012 and devexpress Spreadsheet module.
It is very simple to open excel file and use it.

But now only one excel file is being used (with multiple  sheets), and I would like the file being used to be opened always on startup.

If I add the path and filename to command line arguments, noting happens...

Using devexpress components is very different then vanilla code for me, I am a complete beginner here, so I have no idea how to continue - can someone, please point me in the right direction?

I have made a procedure, to open the file dialog and load the file - I don't know how to "pass" it to devexpress, so the file actually loads to workbook.

```
   Private Sub OpenXls()
        Dim ofd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog
        ofd.DefaultExt = "xls"
        ofd.FileName = "FILE"
        ofd.InitialDirectory = "C:\ref_files"
        ofd.Title = "Select file"
    End Sub
```

As you have pointed out - using the dialog is not the right way.

After some googling I have find out that this should be a better way:

```
Dim workbook As New Workbook
workbook.LoadDocument("C:\ref_files\file.xls", DocumentFormat.xls)
```

I do not get any error, but the file is also not shown...

Do I have to display the document manually after loading?

Comment: Don't use OpenFileDialog. Just open the xlsx (the path is constant, if I understand correctly) in the Form_Shown event.

Comment: I have updated my original question with the code that apparently successfully loads the document (I can use call workbook.ExportToPdf, and the file is perfectly saved in .pdf format), but it is still not showing. What to do here?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using openfiledialogue to open file then you must use command to load the specific file at Form.Load event.

Comment: please show the code where actually you loading excel sheet to devexpress control. @jj6006

Answer (score 0):

The backslash char in `ofd.InitialDirectory = "C:\ref_files"`[escapes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_character_escapes.htm) the letter R to [carrige return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return).

Change this line to `ofd.InitialDirectory = "C:\\ref_files"` (add another backslash).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Another backslash does not change anything - the file is loaded (I can test with converting to .pdf using workbook.exporttoppdf), but it is not shown - I can not edit the file...